# Validating Username and Password in ADF mobile application

Tags: mobile, authentication, oracle-adf

I am developing a simple login page in adf mobile application. following is the piece of code in login (amx) page right now.

```
     <amx:panelGroupLayout id="panelGroupLayout2">
        <amx:inputText value="#{viewcontrollerBundle.USER_NAME}"
                       label="#{viewcontrollerBundle.USER_NAME}"
                       id="UserName"
                       showRequired="true" 
                       required="true"/>
        <amx:inputText
                       id="inputText2"
                       required="true" 
                       showRequired="true"
                       secret="true" label="#{viewcontrollerBundle.PASSWORD}"/>
    </amx:panelGroupLayout>
```

Once the user enters the username and password in the text fields, how do I fetch the values while the user hits on the log in button?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using ADF authentication for the login part? You can take a look [here](http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/08/configuring-authentication-using-remote.html) for the steps. After that, you can use #{securityContext.userName} to access the username.