# Writing code on login button for a mobile application in adf for mobile

Tags: java, oracle-adf-mobile

I am very new to ADF for mobile. I have created a simple page for login. When user enters correct username and password and presses the login button, I should redirect him to next page else display an error message.

But, I am not understanding how to fetch the values of textboxes. 
There is a same question posted here,
 [Validating Username and Password in ADF mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768923/validating-username-and-password-in-adf-mobile-application) which is unanswered.

Please help me with your answers.

Comment: There are no answers for the question mentioned in the link.